# Increase the drive strength of the circuit

Tags: capacitor, pcb, circuit-analysis, ac, circuit-design

Hi I am trying to send a pulse over one circuit and recieve it at another.
For reference I have replaced the circuit that revices the signal with a resistance connected to ground to act as the load. On changing the load values I find that my circuit is not able to drive the pulses and I wanted to know what can be done to help it increase the drive current.

I can't increase the impendence that is make the load lighter so I am stuck with trying to improve the drive strength of the circuit.[image]

I have attached a waveform with a 1k load and no load as reference

Comment: Add a schematic of your circuit.

Comment: Obvious AC coupled signal.  You can restore DC with a buffer and active clamp or bypass the source cap.

Comment: use some sort of buffer circuit before the transmission line

Comment: well by passing the source capacitor is not an options. What kind of buffer should I use?

Comment: What is the timebase on that scope? It looks as if the "source capacitor" is pretty small.

Comment: The source capacitor is a 1micro and the pulse frequency itself should be arround 115.2 Kilo Hertz. the time base id around 40micro I think

Answer (score 1):

The voltage "sag" is because the source of the signal is using AC coupling (which is to say there is a capacitor in series with the signal).

When the current passes through this capactior it either charges or discharges until there is no more current (which happens when voltage across the load is zero).

To decrease the effect, you can either:

- increase the value of the source capacitor so it takes longer to charge or discharge
- bypass the source capacitor entirely (this is most ideal).
- increase the load resistance so there's less current
- increase the frequency so there's less time for the capacitor to charge or discharge

Comment: Increasing the load resistance would mean a huge voltage drop. The source capacitor is acting like a dc block to protect the chip creating the pulses and hence we cant remove it. Finally increasing the capacitor value makes the rise and fall time more spread out casuing issues to recreate the singal at the Rx. At this point I think we need to reconsider the design. Or figure out a way to block dc without using a capacitor removing the source capacitor from the picture

Comment: @DBB The source capacitor is blocking DC and that is exactly the problem! The signal you are trying to transmit "looks like DC" to the capacitor. You can increase the frequency to make it look more like AC, or increase the capacitor value to make it "see as AC" lower frequencies.

Comment: @DBB What is the capacitor protecting the chip from exactly?

Comment: backward DC Flow. there is another unit that needs dc which i dont want flowing into this chip

Comment: @DBB and does the other unit output anything onto this wire?

Comment: Nope nothing but still uses the voltage

Comment: @DBB then why do you think there would be a backward DC flow?

Comment: Well the unit does not output anything but we provide dc input to it from another voltage source in order for it to run and happens on the same line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65874/discussion-between-immibis-and-dbb).